# Некорректно отрабатывает скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

[На сайте](http://klema.by) sticky меню при скроле не открывается. Изначально стиль `display: none;` при клике вижу в инспекторе, что срабатывает `display: block;`, но буквально сразу же срабатывает `display: none;`
Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Почему снова срабатывает `display: none;`

```js
var _set = {
    brk: {
        wdt: 960,
        scrl: 120
    }
};

(function() {
       
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
            if(jQuery('#slider') > 0) {
            jQuery('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
                effect:'fade',
            });
            } else {
                jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
                    effect:'fade',
                });
            }
    });

    // NAVIGATION CALLBACK
    var ww = jQuery(window).width();
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery(".sitenav li a").each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).next().length > 0) {
                jQuery(this).addClass("parent");
            };
        })
        jQuery(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(".left-nav .sitenav").slideToggle('fast');
        });
        jQuery(".toggleMenu-right").click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(".right-nav .phone-numbers").slideToggle('fast');
        });
        adjustMenu();
    })

    // navigation orientation resize callback
    jQuery(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
        ww = jQuery(window).width();
        adjustMenu();
    });

    var adjustMenu = function() {
        function headerSticky() {
            return ww < _set.brk.wdt || jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= _set.brk.scrl;
        }
        
        if (headerSticky()) { //desktop
            jQuery('.header').toggleClass('sticky', true);
        } else {
            jQuery('.header').toggleClass('sticky', false);
        }

    };

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.srchicon').click(function() {
            jQuery('.searchtop').toggle();
            jQuery('.topsocial').toggle();
        }); 
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.logo h1, .services-wrap .one_third h4, .cols-4 h5, .welcomewrap h2').each(function(index, element) {
            var heading = jQuery(element);
            var word_array, last_word, first_part;

            word_array = heading.html().split(/\s+/); // split on spaces
            last_word = word_array.pop();             // pop the last word
            first_part = word_array.join(' ');        // rejoin the first words together

            heading.html([first_part, ' <span>', last_word, '</span>'].join(''));
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        toggleStickyHeader();
        jQuery(window).on('scroll', toggleStickyHeader);
        
        function toggleStickyHeader() {
            if (ww >= _set.brk.wdt) {
                var state = true;
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < _set.brk.scrl) {
                    state = false;
                    jQuery('.left-nav .sitenav').hide();
                }
                jQuery('.header').toggleClass('sticky', state);
            }
   else {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > _set.brk.scrl) {
     jQuery('.js-first-row').css('display', 'none');
     
    }
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
     jQuery('.js-first-row').css('display', 'block');
     
    } 
   }
        }
    })
}());
```

Comment: Дай код `js` скрипта.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в сниппет релеватные HTML и CSS, чтобы мы могли что-то увидеть не переходя на сторонний сайт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В index.html скрипт custom.js подключен два раза. В результате и обработчик клика срабатывает дважды.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сам наверное не заметил бы.